# Estou com problemas em conectar as informações desse dois argumentos, o loop2() não renhonece a definção feita no anterior de "horatrab"

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
def loop1():

    hr_trb = input ('Quantas Horas o Funcionário Trabalhou?:')
    try:
        horatrab = float(hr_trb)
        hora_trab = round (horatrab)
        loop2()
    except:
        print('Valor Inválido, digite o número de horas')
        print (loop1())
  

def loop2():
    
    vlr_hr_nm = input ('Qual o valor da hora trabalhada?:')
    try :
        vlr_hora = float(vlr_hr_nm)
        extra_hour = hora_trab - 40
        if extra_hour > 0:
            vlr_horaex = float(vlr_hora * 1.5)
            pagext = float (vlr_horaex * extra_hour)
            print("Horas Extras Efetuadas:", extra_hour, "\n Valor a ser pago pelas horas extra:", pagext)
            horanorm = float(hora_trab - extra_hour)
            pagnorm = vlr_hora * horanorm
            print('Horas Normais:', horanorm, '\n Valor a ser pago pela hora normal:', pagnorm)
            print('Valor total a ser pago:', (pagnorm + pagext))
            print('Feito!')
        else:
                pagnormso = hora_trab*vlr_hora
                print('Não fez hora extra, receberá, apenas, ', pagnormso)
                print('Feito!')
    except:
        print('Valor Inválido, digite o valor da hora trabalhada')
        print (loop2())


loop1()
```

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor proveito do site.

Comment: [_"Jinx !"_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinx_(game)) @Bacco


Answer (score -2, accepted):

Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler [como criar um Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

O problema que você está enfrentando é que a função `loop2()` não reconhece a definição feita anteriormente para a variável `horatrab`. Isso ocorre porque a variável `horatrab` está definida no escopo local da função `loop1()` e não é acessível na função loop2().

Uma solução para esse problema é passar a variável `horatrab` como um argumento para a função `loop2()`: `loop2(horatrab)` Dessa forma, você pode usar essa informação na função `loop2()`.

Fui rejeitado, mas, sob pressão pública, vou lhe dar a resposta:

```
def loop1():
    hr_trb = input('Quantas horas o funcionário trabalhou?: ')
    try:
        horatrab = float(hr_trb)
        hora_trab = round(horatrab)
        loop2(hora_trab)  # Passando hora_trab como argumento para loop2
    except ValueError:
        print('Valor inválido. Digite o número de horas corretamente.')
        loop1()  # Chama novamente a função loop1 em caso de exceção


def loop2(hora_trab):  # Adicionando hora_trab como parâmetro
    vlr_hr_nm = input('Qual o valor da hora trabalhada?: ')
    try:
        vlr_hora = float(vlr_hr_nm)
        extra_hour = hora_trab - 40
        if extra_hour > 0:
            vlr_horaex = vlr_hora * 1.5
            pagext = vlr_horaex * extra_hour
            print("Horas Extras Efetuadas:", extra_hour)
            print("Valor a ser pago pelas horas extras:", pagext)
            horanorm = hora_trab - extra_hour
            pagnorm = vlr_hora * horanorm
            print('Horas Normais:', horanorm)
            print('Valor a ser pago pela hora normal:', pagnorm)
            print('Valor total a ser pago:', pagnorm + pagext)
            print('Feito!')
        else:
            pagnormso = hora_trab * vlr_hora
            print('Não fez hora extra. Receberá, apenas:', pagnormso)
            print('Feito!')
    except ValueError:
        print('Valor inválido. Digite o valor da hora trabalhada corretamente.')
        loop2(hora_trab)  # Chama novamente a função loop2 em caso de exceção


loop1()
```

Agora, quando a função `loop1()` chama a função `loop2()`, ela passa a variável hora_trab como um argumento. Isso permite que a função `loop2()` acesse e utilize o valor corretamente.

Além disso, fiz algumas outras pequenas alterações no código para melhorar a legibilidade e remover redundâncias. Certifique-se de digitar os valores corretamente ao executar o programa para evitar erros.

Comment: Nossa, muito obrigado, algo tão simples, mas que eu não me atentei. Grato.